# How can I turn off completion cycling in zsh?

Tags: zsh, tab-completion

How do I prevent ZSH cycling through matching completions but instead just presenting a list of remaining possibilities in a list?

On my more recent OS installations I've started getting ZSH cycling behavior when pressing tab. I do not like it and prefer it just show me a list of matches. My older OS installations have this, so I'm guessing some default setting in a newer version of Zsh is the cause. I've tried searching on Google, and diffing my environment variables (`env` output - I can include this them if it helps but it will be very long) but I just can't figure out the right setting(s).

Here is my environment information:

**Works as desired on the following systems (lists matches each time I press tab)**

- `zsh 4.3.12 (i386-apple-darwin11.2.0)`,`Darwin macbookair 11.4.2 Darwin Kernel Version 11.4.2: Thu Aug 23 16:25:48 PDT 2012; root:xnu-1699.32.7~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 i386 MacBookAir4,2 Darwin`
- `zsh 5.1.1 (i686-ubuntu-linux-gnu)`, `Linux nuc2017 4.4.0-96-generic #119-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 12 14:58:51 UTC 2017 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux`

  - fresh Ubuntu install
- `zsh 5.0.8 (x86_64-apple-darwin15.0)`, `Darwin Sridhars-Mac-mini.local 15.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 15.3.0: Thu Dec 10 18:40:58 PST 2015; root:xnu-3248.30.4~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 i386 Macmini6,1 Darwin`

**Does not work as desired (cycles through matches each time I press tab)**

- `zsh 5.1.1 (x86_64-ubuntu-linux-gnu)`, `Linux nuc 4.4.0-21-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 18 18:33:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

  - dist-upgraded my Ubuntu from a previous version
- OS X Sierra (version info not available - it's on my work computer)

---

Things I've tried that don't work:

```
unsetopt menu_complete
```

Comment: Have you tried `unsetopt auto_menu`?

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is `setopt noautomenu`

See https://serverfault.com/questions/109207/how-do-i-make-zsh-completion-act-more-like-bash-completion for a full list of options

Answer (score 1):

If you have a clean Zsh installation with only this in your `~/.zshrc` file

```sh
autoload -Uz compinit && compinit -C
```

then it shows a list of completions the first time you press tab.

However, if you add

```sh
unsetopt AUTO_LIST
```

then this no longer happens and completion starts cycling immediately.

To see if this option has been unset, do

```sh
setopt
```

which shows all options that are different from the default. If the output includes `noautolist`, then `AUTO_LIST` has been unset.